# Add optional fields to django's built-in comments app

Tags: python, django, forms

I wanna add a thumb-up and thumb-down counter as comments' fields.
And I added two IntegerFields to a class called 'MyComment' in models.py.
And I also use a forms.py like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm
from blog.models import MyComment

class MyCommentForm(CommentForm):
    thumbs_up = forms.IntegerField()
    thumbs_down = forms.IntegerField()

def get_comment_model(self):
    return MyComment

def get_comment_create_data(self):
    data = super(MyCommentForm, self).get_comment_create_data()
    data['thumbs_up'] = self.cleaned_data['thumbs_up']
    data['thumbs_down'] = self.cleaned_data['thumbs_down']
    return data
```

After that, when I submit a comment, it says that: thumbs_up and thumbs_down are required.
How do I make them optional, just like the default field "Users' URL"?
Any help will be appreciated.

OK, here's my MyComment model:

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

class MyComment(Comment):
    thumbs_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbs_down = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: give your `MyComment` model.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. Still not working. I'm gonna write my own comment model from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

you should set field optional in model like this:

```
class MyComment(Comment):
    thumbs_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbs_down = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

take a look at [Field options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-options) for more information.
And change your form like this:

```
class MyCommentForm(CommentForm):
    thumbs_up = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    thumbs_down = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

and change `get_comment_create_data` like this:

```
def get_comment_create_data(self):
    data = super(MyCommentForm, self).get_comment_create_data()
    data['thumbs_up'] = self.cleaned_data.get('thumbs_up', 0)
    data['thumbs_down'] = self.cleaned_data.get('thumbs_down', 0)
    return data
```

Comment: @Aida.Mirabadi @Hasan Ramezani I'm sorry, I meant I want this field's default value to be zero. Not excatly like User's URL, which is really null. And still I got this error msg: `(1048, "Column 'thumbs_up' cannot be null")`

Answer (score 0):

You can tell field to be optional by setting "required":

```
class MyCommentForm(CommentForm):
    thumbs_up = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    thumbs_down = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I submit, it shows: "Column 'thumbs_up' cannot be null". And I tried "thumbs_up = forms.IntegerField(default=0,required=False)",but it's wrong too. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Model... it's work.

```
class MyComment(Comment):
    thumbs_up = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    thumbs_down = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
```

blank attribute let you to be set null in admin panel, and null attribute let you set null in database (null=True). i think in your case you just need to set blank=True, because you set default for your fields in model.

Comment: `blank=True` and  `null=True` are for model fields, and in form field we must use `required=False`.

Comment: yes, you are right... i Edited my answer before see your comment...thanks anyway